# How can I allow or ignore apostrophes?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am looking for a regex expression that allows (or ignores) an apostrophe? I'm fairly new to regex and I looked at other similar questions but didn't find the help I need.

I am using a textbox to search an RTB and match all words with a specific or common ending (i.e. the search term inserted in the textbox). Then, I need to pass all matches to a second RTB.

I have tried many different expressions including: `\b\w*[-']\w*\b` but the program either separates the word at the apostrophe, finds only words with an apostrophe, or lists all words as matches?

My sample list of words to search is:

> mi'iria, mi'i, piraria, makuptiaria, netap, hap, kuap, uimikuaptiaria, uhyt, set, uipu'aptiaria, mu'ap, atat, hat, haria, yat. (commas are not in the original list)!

As you can see, there are words that end in "ria" which contain an apostrophe and words that do not. I want to match all words that end with "ria," but I get results like: mi as one match, iria as another match and piraria, makuptiaria, uimikuaptiaria and haria aren't matched?

I need an expression that will allow (or ignore) the apostrophe so that all words that end in "ria" are matched independent of whether they contain an apostrophe or not. Also, words which contain an apostrophe (i.e. similar to mi'iria) should not be separated because of the apostrofe. Can anyone help on this? I am very grateful for any help! Thanks!

Okay, I spent some time tinkering on https://regex101.com/r/X4oL0y/1 and came up with the following expression which matches all words that end with "ria" including those with and those without an apostrophe:

```
\b\w+\'?\w+ria\w*\b
```

However, the w+ria part of this regex represents literal characters. This limits the functionality to words that end with "ria." Is there a way to generically declare the search term the user enters in the textbox as the character(s) to match so that all whole words that end with the search term are matched?

This is my code so far:

```
'Set index:
        Dim index As Integer = 0

        'Find and highlight all search term occurencies:
        While index < RichTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(TextBox1.Text)
            RichTextBox1.Find(TextBox1.Text, index, RichTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
            RichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(RGB(255, 255, 192))
            index = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(TextBox1.Text, index) + 1

        End While

        ' Input string.
        Dim value As String = RichTextBox1.Text

        ' Call Regex.Matches method.
        Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(value, "\b\w+\'?\w+ria\w*\b")

        ' Loop over matches.
        For Each m As Match In matches
            ' Loop over captures.
            For Each c As Capture In m.Captures
                ' Display.
                RichTextBox2.Text += String.Format("Index={0}, Value={1}" & Chr(13), c.Index, c.Value)
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: Try it like this `\b\w*[-']?\w*ria\b` https://regex101.com/r/j1Q5AV/1

Comment: Use `\b\w*(?:[-']\w*)?ria\b` - it's more efficient than making just `[-']` optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the whole word to be matched, you could make the character class optional `[-']?` and add `ria` to the end right before the word boundary

```
 \b\w*[-']?\w*ria\b
```

See a .NET [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cw*%5b-%27%5d%3f%5cw*ria%5cb&i=mi%27iria%0d%0ami%27i%0d%0apiraria%0d%0amakuptiaria%0d%0anetap%0d%0ahap%0d%0akuap%0d%0auimikuaptiaria%0d%0auhyt%0d%0aset%0d%0auipu%27aptiaria%0d%0amu%27ap%0d%0aatat%0d%0ahat%0d%0aharia%0d%0ayat%0d%0ami%27iria)

As per comment of [@ctwheels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3600709/ctwheels) using an optional non capturing group is more efficient.

```
\b\w*(?:[-']\w*)?ria\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `\w*` Match 0+ word chars
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[-']\w*` Match either `-` or `'` and 0+ word chars
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `ria` Match literally
- `\b` Word boundary

See another .NET [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cw*%28%3f%3a%5b-%27%5d%5cw*%29%3fria%5cb&i=mi%27iria%0d%0ami%27i%0d%0apiraria%0d%0amakuptiaria%0d%0anetap%0d%0ahap%0d%0akuap%0d%0auimikuaptiaria%0d%0auhyt%0d%0aset%0d%0auipu%27aptiaria%0d%0amu%27ap%0d%0aatat%0d%0ahat%0d%0aharia%0d%0ayat%0d%0ami%27iria)

Comment: See my comment below the question to make it more efficient (`\b\w*(?:[-']\w*)?ria\b`)

Comment: @ctwheels You are right, it is less steps. I can add it to the answer or you can post it if you want.

Comment: Go ahead, no point in adding a new answer for a minor variance.

Comment: Hey The fourth bird and ctwheels, thanks for those examples! I will try those out! I just edited my post and don't know if you guys saw the edit? I posted an example that I made up, but not sure if that's the way to go? I need to somehow adapt the regex or my code to use the search term entered into a textbox as the characters to match. I need something more generic than just "ria" to make searching and matching more flexible?

Comment: @JohnMichaelWilkinson The pattern `\b\w+\'?\w+ria\w*\b` can also match ria followed by 0+ word characters like rias. If you want to match words that consists of non whitespace chars and end on `ria` you could use `(?<!\S)\S+ria(?!\S)` [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%5cS%2bria%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=mi%27iria%0d%0ami%27i%0d%0apiraria%0d%0amakuptiaria%0d%0anetap%0d%0ahap%0d%0akuap%0d%0auimikuaptiaria%0d%0auhyt%0d%0aset%0d%0auipu%27aptiaria%0d%0amu%27ap%0d%0aatat%0d%0ahat%0d%0aharia%0d%0ayat%0d%0ami%27iria)

Comment: @JohnMichaelWilkinson If the word should contain `ria` you could use `(?<!\S)\S*ria\S*(?!\S)` [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%5cS*ria%5cS*%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=mi%27iria%0d%0ami%27i%0d%0apiraria%0d%0amakuptiaria%0d%0anetap%0d%0ahap%0d%0akuap%0d%0auimikuaptiaria%0d%0auhyt%0d%0aset%0d%0auipu%27aptiaria%0d%0amu%27ap%0d%0aatat%0d%0ahat%0d%0aharia%0d%0ayat%0d%0ami%27iria%0d%0a%0d%0aharias%0d%0aharis)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks for that! I edited my post last night because I realized from everyone's posts that "ria" in the regex is literal chars (see my code above). What I really need to make the program more flexible is a way to search text in RTB1 using a textbox (i.e. insert "ria" or another search term), then pass all matches to RTB2. Is this possible with regex (i.e. recognize search term in a textbox) or do both the code and the regex need altering? It would be even more useful if the resulting list in RTB2 sorted matches alphabetically by the last character! Very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that list is file like this:

```
mi'iria 
mi'i 
piraria
makuptiaria
netap 
hap
kuap
uimikuaptiaria
uhyt
set
uipu'aptiaria
mu'ap
atat
hat
haria
yat
```

Try this one

```
\b[a'-z]*.ria\b
```

Comment: Hey Geralt, not familiar with those expressions? Bit new to regex? I'm using vb.net. Do those expressions work in vb.net?

Comment: I didnt play with vb.net regex I think it's slightly different than POSIX. You need to check it out.

Comment: Okay thanks Geralt, I'll take a look into that. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Geralt, checked into POSIX a little and the WIN10 OS does not appear to be POSIX compliant?

Comment: check out this: https://www.regextester.com with pattern [a-z'].*ria

Comment: Thanks Geralt! However, that expression selects all the words in between so it matches all the words as one match ending with "ria."

Comment: God! I forgot about boundaries \b[a'-z]*.ria\b  Someone mentioned it before. Try it.

Comment: Thanks Geralt! Please see the code of conduct to avoid language that might be offensive to others!